# How to add RSA key to authorized_keys file?

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, ssh-keys, authorized-keys

I've created an RSA public key and I want to add that to `authorized_keys` file, but there is no such file in my Ubuntu 11.10 machine.

How can I add the key to `authorized_keys`?

Answer (score 154):

Make sure when executing Michael Krelin's solution you do the following

```
cat <your_public_key_file> >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Note that without the double `>>` the existing contents of `authorized_keys` will be over-written (nuked!) and that may not be desirable.

Comment: You need to include how to properly cat the public key information, simply copying and pasting it won't do. For example:

Comment: Can you explain why copying / pasting won't work? I am sincerely curious.

Comment: Remember, if running systemd to restart the ssh service, or it won't suck up the new keys `sudo systemctl restart sshd` and won't work

Comment: @Kes, it will. User's `authorized_keys` aren't kept in memory, but read when the user connects.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKrelin-hacker, I did'nt know that!

Comment: @Kes, you're welcome. What you were talking about applies to the files in `/etc/` like `sshd_config`, host keys, etc.

Answer (score 73):

There is already a command in the ssh suite to do this automatically for you. I.e log into a remote host and add the public key to that computers authorized_keys file.

```
ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/key/file user@host.com
```

If the key you are installing is `~/.ssh/id_rsa` then you can even drop the `-i` flag completely.

Much better than manually doing it!

Comment: This advice should be much higher, because this variant does not run the critical danger of damaging your `authorized_keys`-File in a way that might leave you stranded without *any* way to log in.

Comment: Not default port?  Go for `ssh-copy-id -p PORT_NUMBER  USER@REMOTE_MACHINE`

Comment: This answer shows how important and how overlooked reading documentation is. And to add something of merit: you can skip `-i file` and it will copy your default key.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id...` is a chicken-egg problem. If the host requires and SSH key to connect, then `ssh-copy-id` can add my SSH key to `authorized_keys` on the host, no matter how hard I try.

Comment: @RickC if password login is disabled it still works with ssh-agent or you can pass another key for ssh-copy-id to authenticate with using -o "IdentityFile hostkey.rsa" before the host. You may need to use the -f flag too

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: 'log into a remote host and add the public key'... This answer seems to imply you have first login to the remote host and then issue the stated command. As such it is not clear from this answer that the`ssh-copy-id` command should be executed on the client machine (i.e. your PC), not on the ssh host.

Comment: @SamDeMeyer no, What I tried to indicate is that ssh-copy-id command first logs in to the remote host and then adds the public key on that machine.

Comment: @tkarls ah I see. My comment sounded a bit harsh, sorry for that. I didn't know about `ssh-copy-id` and now I use it all the time, so thanks for sharing this piece of knowledge :)

Comment: @tkarls , not sure if one is willing to add their private key to authorized key on remote host. So better you may want change line to hold eg file name as `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: @vinWin you should never expose your private key to anyone! This is why you should use ssh-copy-id since it copies the public key, rather than  the private one. So no risk of exposing your private key by mistake.

Answer (score 65):

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
```

#### To overwrite authorized_keys

```
cat your_key > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

#### To append to the end of authorized_keys

```
cat your_key >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: i have generated key at client side and copied that key to server machine,but using **ssh 192.168.2.7** command it does not allow login.

Comment: Does not allow login saying what?

Comment: when executing this command it asks for password of server.i want a passwordless login

Comment: Is the id (pub part) in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote? Is the id (non pub part) used by ssh when trying to log in? You can try specifying it explicitly with `-i`. Also, you can try `ssh -v` and you can check permissions of your authorized_keys on the remote. And check the logs there.

Comment: Can we somehow check if key is already added? Like it is done by ssh-copy-id for remote system

Comment: @Dmitriusan, of course we can. For instance by grepping the `authorized_keys` file. But if the answer becomes obscure and implement all the features of `ssh-copy-id`, it would probably make sense to replace it with a pointer to ssh-copy-id ;-)

Comment: thanks, I've already figured out that plain grep works since every entry is a single string

Comment: Remember that `.ssh` folder has to be `700`. The `authorized_keys` file should be `600`

Comment: @Naramsim, that's right, but if you forget sshd will remind you (assuming you look up logs when things don't go your way).

Comment: that's what I often use but the ssh-copy-id way should be the accepted answer

Comment: @pycvalade, for starters, the accepted answer should *be* :D And it should be whatever OP accepts. `ssh-copy-id` is definitely the tool one would use if available, but as an answer it may not give a whole picture. Assuming SO is a bit of a learning resource, not just copypaste resource.

Answer (score 42):

I know I am replying too late but for anyone else who needs this, run following command from your local machine

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@192.168.1.1 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

this has worked perfectly fine. All you need to do is just to replace

> user@192.168.1.1

with your own user for that particular host

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Simplest way to add key to remote server, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
>ssh user@serverip -p portnumber 
>sudo bash (if user does not have bash shell else skip this line)
>cd /home/user/.ssh
>echo ssh_rsa...this is the key >> authorized_keys
```

Comment: think its better to indicate last line with public key content with file name as part of echo!